# Check gem path from within Ruby script

Tags: ruby

There are many questions and answers regarding checking the Ruby Gem path from the command line.  However I haven't been able to work out how to check it from within a Ruby script.  I need to do so because I have a `require` which works fine from irb, but fails within my script with a "cannot load such file" error.

How can I check where Ruby is searching for Gems from WITHIN the script?

**EDIT:**

The fix for my `require` turned out to be to add the required gem to the gemspec file as a dependency.  However that doesn't explain why irb was okay but the script wasn't...since the dependency was available, shouldn't they both have found it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `$LOAD_PATH`. Being a list, you can append new search paths to it using `push` or `unshift`. Also, if you're using a Gemfile for your script, you can try to execute your script using this command `bundle exec ruby my_script.rb`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried $LOAD_PATH in my script, it returns the same list as $LOAD_PATH from irb, so it doesn't explain why my require (Sidekiq), works from irb, but not from the script.  I ran the script using `bundle exec` as you recommended.